# Android Need to set image from gallery as paint canvas background

Tags: android, android-canvas, paint

I want to set an image from gallery as a background to the canvas in fingerpaint (api demo sample). I can retrieve the image from gallery but not able to set that as a background. One guess is I can open the image as a input stream, convert that as a array and pass it for bitmap - but I am not sure whether it will work or not and i don't have any clue for how the code will be. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Post your working code so we can see what you know so far.  For instance, do you have a valid Bitmap object created from the resource on disk, and need to know how to draw that bitmap to the canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the onSizeChanged() function to,

```
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        BitmapFactory.Options decode_options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        decode_options.inMutable = true;
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(<file_path>,decode_options);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        mBitmapPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode (SRC_IN));
    }
```

Comment: inMutable option works only for android target 11. Anything else which will work for android 7?

Comment: You can just use, mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(<file_path>); option to decode the bitmap

Comment: I have Same Problem and not getting the proper solution for it. So How i can make it possible ? Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005811/how-to-handle-this-error-while-select-image-from-android-gallery