# How to handle this error while select image from android gallery?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-layout, canvas, android-emulator

I have button of pick image from android gallery in one activity name DrawingActivity. and there is another activity name as DrawingSurface. In DrawingSurface activity i am using thread to draw the canvas and handle it.

Now while i am going to pickup the Image from gallery i got error like this:

```
11-04 12:12:50.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(518): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 12:12:50.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(518): java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started.
11-04 12:12:50.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(518):     at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1322)
11-04 12:12:50.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(518):     at com.example.drawing.DrawingSurface.surfaceCreated(DrawingSurface.java:106)
11-04 12:12:50.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(518):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:532)
11-04 12:12:50.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(518):     at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:206)
11-04 12:12:50.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(518):     at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:3891)
11-04 12:12:50.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(518):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:719)
11-04 12:12:50.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(518):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:719)
11-04 12:12:50.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(518):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:719)
11-04 12:12:50.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(518):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:719)
11-04 12:12:50.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(518):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:744)
11-04 12:12:50.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(518):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
11-04 12:12:50.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(518):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-04 12:12:50.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(518):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-04 12:12:50.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(518):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-04 12:12:50.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(518):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 12:12:50.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(518):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-04 12:12:50.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(518):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-04 12:12:50.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(518):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-04 12:12:50.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(518):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

==========================

The Line where i got this error on DrawingSurface activity is as below:

```
 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start(); // error at this line
}
```

I am using this code to pick image on button pressed:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
            intent.setType("image/*"); 
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);// 
            //startActivity(intent);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),10);
            //finish();
```

So Now can anybudy tell me how i can handle this error ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you are starting a Thread which is already running .

Comment: Yes it seems like that. So how can i handle it ? if it is.

Comment: From the logcat, it seems that the problem happened because you called thread.start() twice. A thread can not be started twice, that's why the exception came out.  I noticed that in the logcat, there is a 'at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged', did you shut down the window and open it again? Maybe this caused the system call 'surfaceCreated (SurfaceHolder holder)' and resulted in this problem. I guess you should make sure to stop the thread in 'public abstract void surfaceDestroyed (SurfaceHolder holder)'.

Comment: u got my answer? try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `thread.isAlive()` before starting the Thread .

Comment: I have use this code. as Sam_k answer. But still got error at this line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this or check Thread object null or not?

first way:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

    switch(requestCode) { 
    case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();


            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

second way :

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        thread.setRunning(true);
        if(!thread.isAlive())  
         thread.start(); // error at this line
}
```

Comment: what is REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE ?

Comment: may be your thread object is running and you again start this. what u want to do excatly. in first way i show you how to take picture from gallary

Comment: Use second way first way is different and REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE is variable.

Comment: ok. See my Edited question. i have try both way but still got error.

Comment: no error in pick the image from gallery but error in draw image on second Activity so problem is not regarding pick the image

Comment: I can give u the code if you are well enough to thread and know how to handle it.

Comment: yes you are right. Problem is not near to pick the Image. but while i am going back from pick image intent, application get crashed. I have put the code in second activity as u have tell but still have same problem.

Comment: sorry i had some work so i cant  reply to you. Are you there?

Comment: Yes i am here. I need help if u can.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4717/discussion-between-sam-k-and-idroid-explorer)